Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^4}{b^4} \geq \frac{a^3}{b^2c}$
Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^4}{b^4} \geq \frac{a^3}{b^2c}$
I thought of unsing AM-GM $\frac{a^4}{b^4} \geq 2* \frac{a^2}{c^2}$ and the analogous.
also i thought using bergstrom but got to nothing useful.

a,b,c are reals ?

Enough to show for positive reals as $|a|^3|b|^{-2}|c|^{-1}\geq a^3 b^{-2}c^{-1}$ and all the terms on the  LHS is positive. Weighted AM-GM approach:
$$
\alpha\frac{a^{4}}{b^{4}}+\beta\frac{b^{4}}{c^{4}}+\gamma\frac{c^{4}}{a^{4}}\geq\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)\sqrt[\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)]{a^{4\left(\alpha-\gamma\right)}b^{4\left(\beta-\alpha\right)}c^{4\left(\gamma-\beta\right)}}
$$
We want the RHS of this to be $\frac{a^3}{b^2c}$ and $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$ so the sum of the three estimates sums to the LHS of the original problem. So the constraints are:
$$\frac{4\left(\alpha-\gamma\right)}{\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)}=3\qquad\frac{4\left(\beta-\alpha\right)}{\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)}=-2\qquad\frac{4\left(\gamma-\beta\right)}{\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)}=-1$$
Solving this yields:
$$
\gamma=\frac{1}{4}(4\alpha-3)\qquad\beta=\frac{1}{2}(2\alpha-1)\Rightarrow\alpha=\frac{3}{4}\qquad\beta=\frac{1}{4}\qquad\gamma=0
$$
Hence by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^{4}}{b^{4}}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{4}\left(3\frac{a^{4}}{b^{4}}+\frac{b^{4}}{c^{4}}\right)\geq\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^{3}}{b^{2}c}$$
